# SQL connection VB.Net and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I work with a Winforms app (VB.net 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2) it's working Ok on my PC. But when I try to test it on another PC (virtual PC), I have a lot of problems.

I have this connection string :

```
Dim mm As String = My.Computer.Name
Dim DB As String = My.Settings.DBname  ' Database name in my app setting 
Con = New SqlConnection("Server=" & mm & ";Database= " & DB & " ;Trusted_Connection=True;")
```

In virtual PC, I installed SQL Server 2008 Express (`SQLEXPR_x86_ENU`), and on another PC I installed SQL 2008 Express, but the app is not connecting to the database.

Sometimes there is `Error 40`, sometimes `Error 26`

What's the best way to solve the problem? Connection string is correct?

How can I make my app work in any PC (32 OR 64 bit) in any OS without any configuration from user (just setup one file) and setup install (My app, report viewer, framework, and SQL) in silent mode?

Comment: 64 bit should not work in 32 bit - so you might want to make it 32 bit.

Comment: also, your connection string seems off. try:

`data source=<server IP or name>; initial catalog=<your database name>; Integrated security= <true for windows authentication. false for userId and Password set in sql server>;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Dim mm As String = My.Computer.Name
Dim DB As String = My.Settings.DBname  ' Database name in my app setting 
Con = New SqlConnection("Data Source =" & mm & ";Initial Catalog= " & DB & " ;Trusted Connection=True; Integrated Security = SSPI")
```

Alternatively, if you have a sql server username and password set up under the login credentials of your database, Integrated security must be false or removed, and replaced with `user id=username; password=yoursecret`

As for your other questions, it's not a good idea to mix up so many topics in one question here on stack overflow (as when a person searches for a specific question, they will only get cluttered multiple questions in a single question asked - which is portrayed by the title of the question)

Have your application build in 32 - bit (64 bit will support it). Right click your project in solution explorer and head to properties > build. You can set it there.

And finally - look into clickonce deployment over [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1.aspx) and look into the [mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/) if you need it to be cross-platform